# Healing request strings with doubled domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This RewriteRule works well in general (files are on the root level):

```
RewriteRule file.xml http://www.example.com/file.php [R=301]
```

But sometimes, very rarely, I see something like this in my logs:

```
pl2-sv2.feedly.com | file.xml | 301
pl2-sv2.feedly.com | /http://www.example.com/file.php | 404
```

Normally the second line is:

```
... | file.php | 200
```

I wonder if this odd behaviour happens on my server or if the starting slash came with the original request (/http://www.example.com/file.xml) and just isn't displayed in the log, because I only see what comes after the root slash:

```
http://www.example.com/http://www.example.com/file.xml
```

If so how could I cut out the second 'http://www.example.com/' then?

Comment: It appears you are replacing "`file.xml`" with "`http://www.example.com/file.php`". Just try "`file.php`" instead.

Comment: I changed it to: RewriteRule file.xml /file.php [R=301]

Comment: No, it didn't change it. Feedly and Feedbin still cause the problem. I checked the times. These requests differ in 1 to serveral seconds while the normal ones have the same second.

Comment: Can you post the complete htaccess please!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

```
RewriteRule file\.xml file.php [L]
```

to avoid redirection.

You should then get:

```
... | file.xml | 200
```